# Drag/drop & delete dynamic text on HTML canvas

Tags: javascript, text, canvas, drag-and-drop

I've found a number of tutorials online for dragging and dropping images and shapes within an HTML canvas. But they all seem to be aimed at moving objects that are generated within the canvas when the page loads. I'm building an app that lets the user click a button on a virtual keyboard, then click on the canvas to have the corresponding number or character appear. This is my code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
            var mathCanvas = document.getElementById("matharea");
            var ctx = mathCanvas.getContext("2d");
            ctx.font="20px Arial";

            var placementCallback = function(){}

            mathCanvas.onselectstart = function(){return false;}

            function insertOne(){placementCallback = function(x, y){ctx.fillText('1', x-6,y+6);}};
            function insertTwo(){placementCallback = function(x, y){ctx.fillText('2', x-6,y+6);}};
            function insertThree(){placementCallback = function(x, y){ctx.fillText('3', x-6,y+6);}};

            mathCanvas.onclick = function(event){
                placementCallback(event.offsetX, event.offsetY);
            }
</script>
```

I cut out some of the insert functions to keep this shorter (the buttons in my HTML have an onclick attribute that calls these functions). I need to be able to select the characters that are placed on the screen and implement drag/drop and delete functionality, but I can't think of a way to do this for text that gets placed on the screen after the page loads (I'm fairly new to Javascript). How would I do this? I'm not expecting anyone to give me the code to do this, but if I could get a push in the right direction, that'd be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that canvas is immediate-mode. Whatever you tell it to put on the canvas it will put on the canvas, instantly. It will not give you the ability to modify that value in any way, shape or form.

Think of it like the difference between MS Paint (or your OS' equivalent) and Photoshop.
In PS, you can have layers which can be moved around and edited, and when you decide your image is done, you save it and it flattens all of that data.

When you make an image in MS Paint, as soon as you click or type, that thing that you put there is there, and it's not moving/being edited unless you erase it, draw over it, or draw a rectangle around a section and move that whole rectangle (including the pixels around what you're trying to edit).

Just calling fillText will paint the words on, that instant, but will not remember what it drew, where it is, what it is, how the text is different from the surrounding pixels, et cetera.

So your generalized solution is that you need to turn your text into objects, and then draw an aspect (the text-content) of those objects to the screen.

If your text changes, you can make a change in the object, and redraw it (because your object will have its `X` and `Y` coordinates stored, and will have its width value stored, using the `context.measureText(textObj.text).width` method/property), and when you click on the canvas, you can check the coordinates of the click, and if those coordinates intersect with your text-object's stored coordinates, then you can modify its position on the screen.

In that regard, you should look into those examples which deal with dragging objects on the canvas.
The button click should be treated as a way to ***CREATE*** one of those objects.

Answer (score -1):

I know this is a lot of code ...  But I didn't want to go through it .. It's PART of something I built a long time ago ...  Just copy and paste into a html file ...  I hope it helps with what you need:

```
        <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
        <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <head>      

        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.17/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/tags/latest/external/jquery.bgiframe-2.1.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/tags/latest/ui/minified/i18n/jquery-ui-i18n.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.7/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
        <script>

        ;(function($) {

        $.fn.insertAtCaret = function (myValue) {

        return this.each(function() {

        //IE support
        if (document.selection) {

        this.focus();
        sel = document.selection.createRange();
        sel.text = myValue;
        this.focus();

        } else if (this.selectionStart || this.selectionStart == '0') {

        //MOZILLA / NETSCAPE support
        var startPos = this.selectionStart;
        var endPos = this.selectionEnd;
        var scrollTop = this.scrollTop;
        this.value = this.value.substring(0, startPos)+ myValue+ this.value.substring(endPos,this.value.length);
        this.focus();
        this.selectionStart = startPos + myValue.length;
        this.selectionEnd = startPos + myValue.length;
        this.scrollTop = scrollTop;

        } else {

        this.value += myValue;
        this.focus();
        }
        });
        };

        })(jQuery);


        $(function go_prev() {
        //When you click on a link with class of poplight and the href starts with a # 
        $('a.poplight[href^=#]').click(function() {
            var popID = $(this).attr('rel'); //Get Popup Name
            var popURL = $(this).attr('href'); //Get Popup href to define size

            //Pull Query & Variables from href URL
            var query= popURL.split('?');
            var dim= query[1].split('&');
            var popWidth = dim[0].split('=')[1]; //Gets the first query string value

            //Fade in the Popup and add close button
            $('#' + popID).fadeIn().css({ 'width': Number( popWidth ) }).prepend('<a href="#" class="close"><img src="close_pop.png" class="btn_close" title="Close Window" alt="Close" /></a>');
            //Define margin for center alignment (vertical   horizontal) - we add 80px to the height/width to accomodate for the padding  and border width defined in the css
            var popMargTop = ($('#' + popID).height() + 90) / 2;
            var popMargLeft = ($('#' + popID).width() + 80) / 2;
            //Apply Margin to Popup
            $('#' + popID).css({
                'top' : 10,
                'margin-left' : -popMargLeft
            });

            //Fade in Background
            $('body').append('<div id="fade"></div>'); //Add the fade layer to bottom of the body tag.
            $('#fade').css({'filter' : 'alpha(opacity=80)'}).fadeIn(); //Fade in the fade layer - .css({'filter' : 'alpha(opacity=80)'}) is used to fix the IE Bug on fading transparencies 

            return false;
        });

        //Close Popups and Fade Layer
        $('a.close, #fade').live('click', function() { //When clicking on the close or fade layer...
            $('#fade , .popup_block').fadeOut(function() {
                $('#fade, a.close').remove();  //fade them both out
            });
            return false;
        });
        });
        </script>



        <script>
        var NumIms = 0;
        var NumTxts = 0;


        //IMAGE VARIABLES
        var ImIds=[];
        var ImNm=[];
        var ImWdth=[];
        var ImHght=[];


        //TEXT VARIABLES
        var TxtIds=[];
        var Txt=[];
        var TxtFnt=[];
        var TxtCol=[];
        var TxtSz=[];


        var MyWidth;
        var MyHeight;
        var img;


        function MoveOver(id,Rid) {
            var img = new Image();
            img.src = Rid;
            MyWidth = img.width;
            MyHeight = img.height;
                $("#UpIm" + id).append("W=" + MyWidth + "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;H=" + MyHeight);
                $("#containment-wrapper").append('<div id="AdIm' + id + '" class="draggable ui-widget-content" style="width:' + MyWidth + 'px; height:' + MyHeight + 'px;  background-image: url(' + Rid + '); position:absolute; left:18px; top:18px;"></div>');


                ImIds[id]="AdIm" + id;
                ImNm[id]=Rid;
                ImWdth[id]=MyWidth;
                ImHght[id]=MyHeight;

                $( "#AdIm" + id ).draggable();
                var f = document.getElementById('UpIm' +id);
                var Olddiv = document.getElementById('ul' + id);
                f.removeChild(Olddiv);
        }
        </script>
        <script>
        function removeIm(id) {
            var f = document.getElementById('files');
            var Folddiv = document.getElementById('UpIm' + id);
            f.removeChild(Folddiv);

            var d = document.getElementById('containment-wrapper');
            var Dolddiv = document.getElementById('AdIm' + id);
            d.removeChild(Dolddiv);
            ImIds.splice(id,1,"deleted");

        }
        </script>


        <script type="text/javascript" >
        var iid = -1;
        var pic_real_width, pic_real_height, img;

        function removeFormIm(Rid,id) {
            var f = document.getElementById('files');
            var Folddiv = document.getElementById('UpIm' + id);
            f.removeChild(Folddiv);

            var d = document.getElementById('containment-wrapper');
            var Dolddiv = document.getElementById('AdIm' + id);
            d.removeChild(Folddiv);
        }

        </script>


        <style>
        #containment-wrapper { width: 845px; height:150px; border:2px solid #ccc; }

        #fade { /*--Transparent background layer--*/
            display: none; /*--hidden by default--*/
            background: #000;
            position: fixed; left: 0; top: 0;
            width: 100%; height: 100%;
            opacity: .80;
            z-index: 9999;
        }
        .popup_block{
            display: none; /*--hidden by default--*/
            background: #fff;
            padding: 20px;
            border: 20px solid #ddd;
            float: left;
            font-size: 1.2em;
            position: fixed;
            top: 50%; left: 50%;
            z-index: 99999;
            /*--CSS3 Box Shadows--*/
            -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #000;
            -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #000;
            box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #000;
            /*--CSS3 Rounded Corners--*/
            -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
            -moz-border-radius: 10px;
            border-radius: 10px;
        }


        .t_t{
            display: none; /*--hidden by default--*/
            background: #fff;
            padding: 20px;
            border: 20px solid #ddd;
            float: left;
            font-size: 1.2em;
            position: fixed;
            top: 50%; left: 50%;
            z-index: 99999;
            /*--CSS3 Box Shadows--*/
            -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #000;
            -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #000;
            box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #000;
            /*--CSS3 Rounded Corners--*/
            -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
            -moz-border-radius: 10px;
            border-radius: 10px;
        }
        img.btn_close {
            float: right;
            margin: -55px -55px 0 0;
        }
        /*--Making IE6 Understand Fixed Positioning--*/
        *html #fade {
            position: absolute;
        }
        *html .popup_block {
            position: absolute;
        }
        </style>


        <script>
        function changeTxt(id){
            var my_txt;
            my_txt =  document.getElementById('TxtIn' + id).value;
            document.getElementById('AdText' + id).innerHTML = my_txt;
            Txt[id] = my_txt;
            }
        </script>
        <script>
        function makebold(id){
        $('#TxtIn' + id).insertAtCaret('<b></b>');
        changeTxt(id);
            }

        function makeitalic(id){
        $('#TxtIn' + id).insertAtCaret('<i></i>');
        changeTxt(id);
            }

        function makecenter(id){

            var my_txt;
            my_txt =  document.getElementById('TxtIn' + id).value;
            $("textarea#TxtIn" + id).val('<center>' + my_txt + '</center>');
            changeTxt(id)
            }

        function makebr(id){
        $('#TxtIn' + id).insertAtCaret('<br>');
        changeTxt(id);
            }

        function makelink(id){
            get_color = document.getElementById('fcolor' + id).value;
            $('#TxtIn' + id).insertAtCaret('<a href="http://" style="text-decoration:none; color:#' + get_color + ';"></a>');
            changeTxt(id);
            }
            function makeh2(id){
        $('#TxtIn' + id).insertAtCaret('<H2></H2>');
        changeTxt(id);
            }
            function makeh3(id){
        $('#TxtIn' + id).insertAtCaret('<H3></H3>');
        changeTxt(id);
            }
        </script>
        <script>
        function callFontType(id){
            var type;
            type = document.getElementById('ftype' + id).value;
            document.getElementById('AdText' + id).style.fontFamily=type;
            TxtFnt[id] = type;
            }
        </script>

        <script>
        function CxColor(id){
            var Clor;
            Clor = document.getElementById('fcolor' + id).value;
            Clor = '#' + Clor;
            document.getElementById('AdText' + id).style.color=Clor;
            TxtCol[id] = Clor;
            }
         </script>

        <script>
        function changeFSize(id){

            var my_size;
            my_size =  document.getElementById('SizeIn' + id).value;
            my_size = my_size + 'px';
            document.getElementById('AdText' + id).style.fontSize = my_size;
            TxtSz[id] = my_size;
            }
        </script>

        <script>
        var id = -1;
                function addFormField() {
        id = id + 1;
        $("#divTxt").append("<span id='row" + id + "'><small>Add: to textbox:</small><input value=\"b\" onclick=\"makebold(" + id + ")\" title=\"bold: &lt;b&gt;text&lt;/b&gt;\" type=\"button\"><input value=\"i\" onclick=\"makeitalic(" + id + ")\" title=\"italic: &lt;i&gt;text&lt;/i&gt;\" type=\"button\"><input value=\"center\" onclick=\"makecenter(" + id + ")\" title=\"center: &lt;center&gt;text&lt;/center&gt;\" type=\"button\"><input value=\"BR\" onclick=\"makebr(" + id + ")\" title=\"BR: &lt;br&gt;\" type=\"button\"><input value=\"link\" onclick=\"makelink(" + id + ")\" title=\"link: &lt;a href= &gt;URL&lt;/a&gt;\" type=\"button\"><input value=\"H2\" onclick=\"makeh2(" + id + ")\" title=\"H2: &lt;H2&gt;text&lt;/H2&gt;\" type=\"button\"><input value=\"H3\" onclick=\"makeh3(" + id + ")\" title=\"H3: &lt;H3&gt;text&lt;/H3&gt;\" type=\"button\"><br><table><tr><td><a onClick='removeFormField(\"#row" + id + "\",\"" + id + "\"); return false;'>REMOVE</a></td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;<textarea cols=50 rows=5 name='txt[]' id='TxtIn" + id + "'  onKeyUp=\"changeTxt(" + id + ");\">Text " + id + "</textarea></td><td>Font:<select onChange=\"callFontType(" + id + ");\" id=\"ftype" + id + "\"><option value=\"Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif\">Arial</option><option value=\"Impact, Charcoal, sans-serif\">Impact</option><option value=\"Palatino Linotype, Book Antiqua, Palatino, serif\">Palatino</option><option value=\"Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif\">Tahoma</option><option value=\"Century Gothic, sans-serif\">Century Gothic</option><option value=\"Lucida Sans Unicode, Lucida Grande, sans-serif\">Lucida Grande</option><option value=\"Arial Black, Gadget, sans-serif\">Arial Black</option><option value=\"Times New Roman, Times, serif\">Times New Roman</option><option value=\"Arial Narrow, sans-serif\">Arial Narrow</option><option value=\"Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif\">Verdana</option><option value=\"Copperplate, Copperplate Gothic Light, sans-serif\">Copperplate</option><option value=\"Lucida Console, Monaco, monospace\">Lucida Console</option><option value=\"Gill Sans, Gill Sans MT, sans-serif\">Gill Sans</option><option value=\"Trebuchet MS, Helvetica, sans-serif\">Trebuchet</option><option value=\"Courier New, Courier, monospace\">Courier New</option><option value=\"Georgia, Serif\">Georgia</option></select><br>Color: <input id=\"fcolor" + id + "\" class=\"color\" value=\"000000\"><img src=\"go.png\" style=\"vertical-align:middle;\" onClick='CxColor(" + id + ");'><br>Size: <input type='text' size='4' value=\"12\" name='txt[]' id='SizeIn" + id + "'  onKeyUp=\"changeFSize(" + id + ");\"></td></tr></table><br><hr style=\"width:800px; float:left;\"><br></span>");
        $("#containment-wrapper").append('<span id="AdText' + id + '" class="draggable ui-widget-content" style="position:absolute; left:18px; top:18px; font-size:16px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">Text ' + id + '</span>');
        $( "#AdText" + id ).draggable();//{ containment: "#containment-wrapper", scroll: true }

        $('#fcolor' + id).load(jscolor.init());

        TxtIds[id] = "AdText" + id;
        Txt[id] = "Ad Text";
        TxtFnt[id] = "Arial";
        TxtCol[id] = "#000000";
        TxtSz[id] = "16";


        $('#row' + id).highlightFade({
            speed:1000
        });
        document.getElementById("id").value = id;
    }
        function removeFormField(Rid,id) {
            $(Rid).remove();
            var d = document.getElementById('containment-wrapper');
            var olddiv = document.getElementById('AdText' + id);
            d.removeChild(olddiv);
            TxtIds.splice(id,1,"deleted");
        }
        function GetURL(id) {

                var gurl;
                var Ims = "";
                var len=ImIds.length;
                NumIms = 0;
                NumTxts = 0;

                //############ Start Get Images for URL ##############
                for(var i=0; i<len; i++) {
                NumIms++;
                var value = ImIds[i];
                Ims += '&ImName' + i + '=' + value;
                if (value != "deleted"){

                value = ImNm[i];
                Ims += '&ImNm' + i + '=' + value;
                value = ImWdth[i];
                Ims += '&ImWidth' + i + '=' + value;
                value = ImHght[i];
                Ims += '&ImHeight' + i + '=' + value;
                value = $('#AdIm' + i).position().left - $('#AdIm' + i).closest('#containment-wrapper').position().left;
                Ims += '&ImLt' + i + '=' + value;
                value = $('#AdIm' + i).position().top - $('#AdIm' + i).closest('#containment-wrapper').position().top;
                Ims += '&ImTop' + i + '=' + value;
                }
                }
                //########### End Get Images For URL #####################
                len=TxtIds.length;
                //############ Start Get Texts for URL ##############
                for(var i=0; i<len; i++) {
                NumTxts++;
                var value = TxtIds[i];
                Ims += '&TxtName' + i + '=' + escape(value);
                if (value != "deleted"){
                value = Txt[i];
                Ims += '&Txt' + i + '=' + escape(value);
                value = TxtFnt[i];
                Ims += '&TxtFnt' + i + '=' + escape(value);
                value = TxtCol[i];
                value = value.substring(1);
                Ims += '&TxtCol' + i + '=' + escape(value);
                value = TxtSz[i];
                Ims += '&TxtSz' + i + '=' + escape(value);
                value = $('#AdText' + i).position().left - $('#AdText' + i).closest('#containment-wrapper').position().left;
                Ims += '&TxtLt' + i + '=' + value;
                value = $('#AdText' + i).position().top - $('#AdText' + i).closest('#containment-wrapper').position().top;
                Ims += '&TxtTop' + i + '=' + value;
                }
                }
                //########### End Get Texts For URL #####################





                gurl = "ad.php?AdType=hero&ImNum=" + NumIms + "&TxtNum=" + NumTxts;
                gurl = gurl + Ims;
                //alert(gurl);gurl = escape( gurl );
                $("#genurl" + id).html('<textarea id="fe_text" cols=50 rows=5 name="ad_url">' + gurl + '</textarea><br><br><table><tr><td><font style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:16px; color:#009999">Preview Gernerated Ad:</font></td><td><a href="' + gurl + '" target="_blank"><img src="view.png"></a></td></tr></table><br>');

            }


        </script>

           <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#myform1").validate({
                    debug: false,
                    submitHandler: function(form) {
                        // do other stuff for a valid form
                        $.post('process.php', $("#myform1").serialize(), function(data) {
                            $('#results').fadeIn('fast');
                            var mySplitResult = data.split("|||");
                        if(mySplitResult[1] !== "fail" && mySplitResult[1] !== "disable"){
        $('#upd1').html('<textarea id="fe_text" cols=50 rows=5 readonly="readonly">' + mySplitResult[1] + '</textarea><br />');
                        }
                        $('#results').html(mySplitResult[0]);
                            $('#prev1').html(mySplitResult[1]);
                                setTimeout(function() {
                                $('#results').fadeOut('slow');
                                }, 2500);


                        });
                    }
                });
            });



            </script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="jscolor.js"></script>

        </head>

        <body>

        <div id="containment-wrapper">
        <!--<span id="AdText0" class="draggable ui-widget-content">For Testing ...  </span> -->
        </div>

        <div style="margin-left:50px;">
        <center><p style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:24px; color:#FF0099">Text Field Input</p>
        <p><a href="#" onClick="addFormField(); return false;"  style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:16px; color:#6633FF;">Add Text Field</a></p></center>
        <form action="#" method="get" id="form1" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:16px;">
        <input type="hidden" id="id" value="1">
        <div id="divTxt"></div>
        </form>
        </div>





        <!-- End Hidden Divs -->
        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: If you are going to vote down ...  Comment ...  And if it's for lack of explanation, the user (Ben) has 5 open questions -- all answered and no accepts ...